# Delphi Unit test coverage with teamcity

Tags: delphi, teamcity, dunit

This may be a stupid question, but i can find any answers anywhere.
I am setting up teamcity CI for building my delphi projects and am trying to get teamcity to run my DUnit tests and show the out put in the teamcity build log UI but i have no idea how to get this to work.

Any advice or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Found a possible solution will post if it works.

I found a solution, i have to force the unit test runner in the project to run in command runner and not the GUIRunner, them teamcity is all happy like a dog on a pill.

Thanks for the help!

Regards nico

Comment: http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2010/05/25/how-to-set-up-a-continous-integration-server-with-delphi-dunit-and-teamcity/

Comment: So you tried that. What happened?

Comment: Sorry i try running the unit test exe as the top mentioned blog post sugests but it runs for ever and nothing happens.

Comment: Then do some debugging. Why is it running forever?

Comment: thats the thing my experience with teamcity is very limited, i got it to compile and build the projects, it is just the unit tests that is not or are running but not giving any output.

Comment: So do some debugging. We cannot debug it for you. The code is running on your machine. So get it to spew out diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Force the unit test runner in the project to run in command runner and not the GUIRunner.